# Drop down selection is not getting possible to choose an element from the list even using select class and Action class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

As my website code was written in Angular-6. I am using java selenium for automation.

As I try to use select class for selecting dropdown menu then unable to identify element.
Again I try to use Action class for selection drop down menu then i was able to click on drop down but unable to choose element from drop down when i run automation.

code which i used below :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: Add relevant HTML Block.

Comment: there is lot of bunch stuff code to share here. Instead of that just say how you were using drop down selection code here

Comment: Please refer How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please post HTML code of the dropdown first

Comment: Next to the missing html code, do you get any exception? If yes, what exception?